# Prerequisites for Perl

Tags: perl, cgi, mod-perl

I am new to developing a website using Perl CGI scripts.

What are the prerequisites for Perl?

Please give me some basic ideas or some good tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean: what prerequisite knowledge would help you learn Perl?

The Perl language grew out of the best features of the Unix commands grep, awk, sed, and shell scripts, plus some C. If you are strong in those areas, Perl will seem like a good fit. You'd already be used to cryptic variable names, quick-n-dirty looping constructs, dynamic typing, regular expressions, and standard input/output.

Answer (score 0):

First decide if you are writing a CGI script or an Apache handler.  The 2 are coded completely differently, but both have their advantages and disadvantages.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run your script using CGI (or FCGI), I recommend [this tutorial](http://www.lies.com/begperl/) for beginning programmers. It will help you through creating simple forms. If you already know a bit about programming a script language, you will be able to skim-read a lot of that. If you are a new programmer, you might also want zo look up a few alternatives, like [coding CGI scripts with Python](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~lab2q/), a language often thought to be better suited to new programmers.

Answer (score 0):

I would point you towards [learn.perl.org](http://learn.perl.org/), the [Modern Perl book](http://www.onyxneon.com/books/modern_perl/index.html) by chromatic, and the overview of [web frameworks on the Perl 5 wiki](https://www.socialtext.net/perl5/index.cgi?web_frameworks). Also make sure that the tutorials and articles you use are relatively recent. Perl has been around for a long time and modern Perl is different from what people wrote 10 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest starting with [PSGI](http://plackperl.org/).  It is somewhat new (compared to mod_perl), but it's Perl's answer to Python WSGI.  Most of the large frameworks support it, as does other interesting projects like Starman.  I would start there and Google anything I don't understand.